# Dropbox Java SDK. how to hide app public and secret key

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

this was originally posted in the dropbox developer forums but didnt get any response, so I try here on SO.

when developing an application using the dropbox java sdk, it is recommended by the documentation to write something like this:

```java
final static private String APP_KEY = "...";
final static private String APP_SECRET = "...";
```

isnt it relatively easy to find out those two strings even after the application has been compiled and/or signed by just looking at the class file?

in other words the secret key is no longer secret once i publish my app?

are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

My guesses are that the Dropbox documentation meant that this code should be implemented if you write **java server code**. If you deploy the java application you should create an authentication with your server before allowing the clients blind access to dropbox.